# Source file in CSC cannot be found

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, nuget-package, csc

After a struggle with creating a database (first with an entity framework, after without), we have a database (and an EntityModel_HFFContext file we don't use, it's not connected). Normal work proceeded, and I installed a NuGet-package for an MVC sitemap.

From that moment, the project worked fine, but after a couple of days two warnings came up about two files missing: "The parent file, 'EntityModel_HFF.tt', for file 'locatie.cs' cannot be found in the project file." ("HFF" is the project name in here) and then those [multiplied themselves into errors:](http://s15.postimg.org/dg5vlx2aj/errornotfound.png) "Source file 'locatie.cs' cannot be found" in a CSC file I cannot find.

These two files ('locatie.cs' and 'klant.cs') are not in any view, but somehow they are displayed outside all folders, saying they do not excist ([see this screencapture](http://s29.postimg.org/caxnx4sdj/errorcsc.png)). I have tried to delete those files manually, but that did not have any success. I have tried some other ways too, but that resulted into the complete deletion of the database, so now I am somewhat desperate.

I have no idea where to look and what to do, to get rid of these two files (or probably references to these files, since we don't use them at all), so I don't have these errors anymore. Has anyone of you have a clue of where I need to look (e.g. where this CSC file is) and what I need to adjust to fix this?

Maybe it can be useful to know I use Visual Studio 2013.

**Update**

I fixed the errors by unloading the project, editing the .csproj file and commenting out

```
<Compile Include="klant.cs">
    <DependentUpon>EntityModel_HFF.tt</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
```

(and the other one too). Now these errors are gone - is this a safe way to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reason why you get the error is because when you deleted the `locatie.cs` and `klant.cs` file, you didn't remove them from the project solution itself, therefore, Visual Studio is expecting the file to be part of the project but is unable to find them, which explains the yellow warning signs.

Like what you said, all you have to do is to remove the files from the solution as they no longer exists. So yes, it is safe to comment out that portion in the .csproj file.

Although, I would like to mention that you didn't have to go to that much trouble, all you had to do was to delete the file in your solution in Visual Studio, since they no longer exists anyway.